# Setting up cron jobs on cPanel

Tags: cron, cli

Need your help....I'm trying to setup cron jobs using the cli.php command given in the documentation....I'm able to run it directly through the terminal...but when I schedule it via cPanel its gives me an error 'cli.php can only be run from command line.'

Comment: More information about your setup might help...

Comment: @guru316 if you provide more info on your setup - I can provide CPanel instructions.  I would need to know what version of Civi and what CMS.

Answer (score 1):

if your user has cron access, you can always create a file, call it cron for simplicity sake, in the file add the command you wish to run, for example mine is a bit interesting cause I have to export my civicrm settings at the same time:

```
export CIVICRM_SETTINGS="/home/domain/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php"    
cv api --user=cron job.execute
```

mind you, thats using the CV command, however, this can still be implemented via the cli.php.
Example:

```
 /path/to/php /path/to/civcrm/bin/cli.php \
  -s example.org \
  -u myusername \
  -p mypassword \
  -e Job \
  -a execute
```

save that in the file you created earlier (with your changes of course), then with cpanels cron, just  set the command/job to execute:

```
sh cron > /dev/null
```

or

```
sh cron > /home/domain/logs/cron.log
```

just make sure the file is outside of the web folder and is executable.