# cli.php can only be run from command line

Tags: wordpress, cron, cron-job

Using WordPress 5.4 and CiviCRM Version 5.18.4.  Hosting with InmotionDirect, managing via Cpanel.

Trying to follow the instructions to set up our cron job.  I got the command line to work, finally, as:
php public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php -s [site] -u [user] -p [password] -e Job -a execute

It worked, and I thought I was done.  Plugged it into the Crom job list in Cpanel and sat back.

Error via email: "cli.php can only be run from command line."

Well, nobody mentioned that in the instructions.  Is that a universal rule, or is just my hosting service being fussy?

Based on an answer here ([Setting up cron jobs on cPanel](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20620/setting-up-cron-jobs-on-cpanel)) I tried putting the command line in a file and having the cron job command be just sh thatfile.  Same error.

Is there a workaround?  Or do I have to manually install yet another program like wp-cli just to run my jobs?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I seem to have resolved it by replacing cli.php with cron.php in the command line.  Of course it didn't do anything when I ran the command from the terminal, but I plugged it into the cron jobs list and it seems to be executing the jobs now.  I am just lucky I spotted the "cron.php" file in the bin folder, and took a chance on it being what I needed.

My sympathies to any novice like me who has to set up Cron Jobs for CiviCRM -- the instructions may make sense to a Linux expert or php programmer, but to complete this simple and essential task, it has taken me months.

Thanks for your help, folks!

Comment: Ok if it's working great just now it sounds like you're simulating a web request from the command line, by running the fcgi binary against a script meant to be called from the web. See how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is maybe the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886539/why-does-php-sapi-not-equal-cli-when-called-from-a-cron-job

The key line is `Do not always expect /usr/bin/php to be a link to php-cli binary`.

Meaning: In your cron command give the full path to the exact version of the php binary that you want, which might be something like `/usr/bin/php-cli`. I'm not familiar with InmotionDirect, but they probably have `php` linked to `cgi-fcgi`, so you need to find the right full path to the cli version of php. I'm sure InmotionDirect can tell you. Possibly this: https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/questions/communities/1/topics/10968-using-cli-version-of-php-with-cron

Comment: Well, as I said, my command is:
php public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php -s [site]-u [user] -p [password] -e Job -a execute

I have verified that, at least when run from the terminal, this works, so I guess this is the right path to the cli.php.  But maybe "cli.php" is not what I should be running at all (since the cli means command line interface).  If I am searching in my files on the server for an equivalent binary that will run from a cron job, would it be called cron.php?  Would it take the same parameters, etc?

Comment: When run from the terminal your PATH or a wrapper might be different than from cpanel cron. Based on the article on the hosting company's site I would change php to php-cli in your cron command, the php at the start of the line.